# VHDL up/down counter error counting

Tags: vhdl

Im trying to make a counter which counts up to 3 then counts down to 0 etc..
example: 0 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 2 1 0...

What I did:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Counter is
   port(
     Clock: in std_logic;
     Reset: in std_logic;
     Output: out std_logic_vector(0 to 1 ));
end Counter;

architecture Behavioral of Counter is
   signal temp: std_logic_vector(0 to 1);
   signal down: std_logic := '0';
begin   process(Clock,Reset)
   begin
      if Reset='0' then
         temp <= "00";
         down<= '0';
      elsif(rising_edge(Clock)) then
            if temp="11" then
                down<= '1';
            elsif temp="00" then
                down<='0';
            end if;

            if down='0' then
                temp <= temp +1;
            else 
                temp <= temp-1;
            end if;

      end if;
   end process;
   Output <= temp;
end Behavioral;
```

Somehow the output is going from 3 to 0 without showing the middle numbers..
What is wrong?

Comment: perhaps it's overflowing rather than counting down. Did you consider `down` to be variable rather than signal, and therefore using `:=` (immediate assignment) rather than `<=` (state at next clock)?

Comment: Strange, that you can add anything to std_logic_vector. What tool do you use? And it's just as @diginoise said. When `temp = "11"` you assign `down <= '1'` but it happens after process finishes. So it is still '0' when it is checked in `if down='0' then`. That's why it overflows. Same in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Staszek They're using the std_logic_unsigned legacy pacakge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not looking at all the signals: look at `down` to see what happens. Because you are using clocked/synchronous logic, `down` is changed in the clock cycle where `temp` is detected 3, so it will have effect *one clock cycle later*. I.e. when `temp` is 3, `down` will still be 0, thus (3+1) mod 4 = 0.

One possible solution is to be one step ahead of this: Change `down` *one clock cycle earlier*... when `temp`=2.

One other problem is that you are combining the non-standardized packages `STD_LOGIC_ARITH` and `STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED` with logic arrays in reverse direction. That can give unpredictable results. Please use standardized packages. Example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity counter is
    port(
        clk    : in  std_logic;
        rst_n  : in  std_logic;
        output : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture behavioral of counter is
    use ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
    signal temp : unsigned(output'range) := (others => '0');
    signal down : std_logic := '0';
begin
    process(clk, rst_n)
    begin
        if rst_n = '0' then -- why asynchronous reset??
            temp <= (others => '0');
            down <= '0';
        elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
            if temp = 2 then
                down <= '1';
            elsif temp = 1 then
                down <= '0';
            end if;
            if down = '0' then
                temp <= temp + 1;
            else 
                temp <= temp - 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    output <= std_logic_vector(temp);
end architecture;
```

-

```
entity counter_tb is end entity;

library ieee;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

architecture behavioral of counter_tb is
    signal clk : std_logic;
    signal rst_n : std_logic;
    signal output : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin
    DUT: entity work.Counter
        port map(
            clk => clk,
            rst_n => rst_n,
            output => output
        );

    rst_n <= '1';
    process
    begin
        clk <= '0', '1' after 1 ns;
        wait for 2 ns;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Next time please add your test bench to form a complete set...
and please don't use 3-space indentation :( use 4, like everybody does)